# Create Line Chart in Android using MPAndroidChart library

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I want to create a chart as shown in the image. Till now I have tried it to achieve using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

[image: Line Chart]

However, I tried so far and unable to make it.

My codes are as below:

**Layout:**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/lineChart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity File:**

```java
package com.app.androidchart;
    
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IndexAxisValueFormatter;
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawLineChart();
    }

    private void drawLineChart() {
        LineChart lineChart = findViewById(R.id.lineChart);
        List<Entry> lineEntries = getDataSet();
        LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineEntries, "Work");
        lineDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        lineDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(true);
        lineDataSet.setLineWidth(2);
        lineDataSet.setColor(Color.RED);
        lineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.YELLOW);
        lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(6);
        lineDataSet.setCircleHoleRadius(3);
        lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
        lineDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true);
        lineDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
        lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);
        lineDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.STEPPED);

        LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);
        lineChart.getDescription().setTextSize(12);
        lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setDrawMarkers(false);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        lineChart.animateY(1000);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1.0f);
        lineChart.setData(lineData);

        ArrayList<String> xAxisLabel = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxisLabel.add("Rest");
        xAxisLabel.add("Work");
        xAxisLabel.add("2-up");

        XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setAxisMaximum(3);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisLabel) {
            @Override
            public String[] getValues() {
                return super.getValues();
            }
        });

        YAxis yAxis = lineChart.getAxisLeft();
        yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
        yAxis.setAxisMaximum(24);

        lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

        lineChart.invalidate();

    }

    private List<Entry> getDataSet() {
        List<Entry> lineEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(0, 4));
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(1, 3));
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(2, 6));
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(3, 8));
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(4, 2));
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(5, 3));
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(6, 1));
        return lineEntries;
    }

}
```

Above is the entire code to achieve as per the shared image.

I want solutions for the below things:

- Set X-Axis at the left side
- Set Y-Axis at the top side
- Assign data in which the X-axis has 3 items and Y-Axis has 24 (here I didn't find any method inside the Entry class of MPAndroid Chart.)

Please suggest me some solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably the moderators are downvoting. When you ask a question, you have to provide the community with some code snippets of what you have tried so that the problem is reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

in the example image XAxis should be on the top with 25 labels 0 to 24, and YAxix should be on the left with 3 labels,

The ValueFormatter should be added with YAxis, not XAxix because it needs to show string values.

So the right code will be like this

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawLineChart();
}


private void drawLineChart() {
    LineChart lineChart = findViewById(R.id.lineChart);
    List<Entry> lineEntries = getDataSet();
    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineEntries, "Work");
    lineDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    lineDataSet.setLineWidth(2);
    lineDataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    lineDataSet.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(6);
    lineDataSet.setCircleHoleRadius(3);
    lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
    lineDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true);
    lineDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    lineDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.CYAN);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.STEPPED);

    LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);
    lineChart.getDescription().setTextSize(12);
    lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    lineChart.animateY(1000);
    lineChart.setData(lineData);

    // Setup X Axis
    XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1.0f);
    xAxis.setXOffset(1f);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(25);
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(24);

    // Setup Y Axis
    YAxis yAxis = lineChart.getAxisLeft();
    yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
    yAxis.setAxisMaximum(3);
    yAxis.setGranularity(1f);

    ArrayList<String> yAxisLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    yAxisLabel.add(" ");
    yAxisLabel.add("Rest");
    yAxisLabel.add("Work");
    yAxisLabel.add("2-up");

    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            if(value == -1 || value >= yAxisLabel.size()) return "";
            return yAxisLabel.get((int) value);
        }
    });

    lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    lineChart.invalidate();
}
```

And this full dummy data for testing to give you the same result as your example image

```java
private List<Entry> getDataSet() {
    List<Entry> lineEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(0, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(1, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(2, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(3, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(4, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(5, 1));

    lineEntries.add(new Entry(6, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(7, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(8, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(9, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(10, 2));

    lineEntries.add(new Entry(11, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(12, 1));

    lineEntries.add(new Entry(13, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(14, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(15, 2));

    lineEntries.add(new Entry(16, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(17, 1));

    lineEntries.add(new Entry(18, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(19, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(20, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(21, 2));

    lineEntries.add(new Entry(22, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(23, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(24, 1));
    return lineEntries;
}
```

The result on my device
[image]